# Fail/Error in cordapp-template FlowTest progressTracker hasn't been started

Tags: testing, corda

when I try to run this tests for the flows in the cordapp-template:

```
@Test
fun flowRecordTransactionInBothVaults() {

    val flow = IOUFlow.Initiator(1,b.info.legalIdentity)
    val future = a.services.startFlow(flow).resultFuture
    net.runNetwork()
    val signedTx = future.getOrThrow()

    for (node in listOf(a,b)) {
        assertEquals(signedTx, node.storage.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(signedTx.id))
    }
}
```

I get this error: Progress tracker hasn't been started

```
[INFO ] 15:14:52.144 [Mock network] AbstractNetworkMapService.processRegistrationRequest - Added node CN=Mock Company 3,O=R3,L=New York,C=US to network map

[WARN ] 15:14:52.172 [Mock network] [a11087fc-381d-4547-8736-5265c334c71f].maybeWireUpProgressTracking - ProgressTracker has not been started

[WARN ] 15:14:52.191 [Mock network] [0dcfa270-b1af-40e9-92f1-411334cf0c73].run - Terminated by unexpected exceptionkotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
at com.template.flow.IOUFlow$Acceptor$call$1.checkTransaction(TemplateFlow.kt:225) ~[main/:?] 

at net.corda.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:201) ~[corda-core-0.13.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:177) ~[corda-core-0.13.0.jar:?]

[WARN ] 15:14:52.202 [Mock network] [a11087fc-381d-4547-8736-5265c334c71f].run - Terminated by unexpected exceptionnet.corda.core.flows.FlowSessionException: Counterparty flow on CN=Mock Company 3,O=R3,L=New York,C=US had an internal error and has terminated
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.erroredEnd(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:382) ~[corda-node

[WARN ] 15:14:52.203 [Mock network] [a11087fc-381d-4547-8736-5265c334c71f].uncaughtException - Caught exception from flowjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Progress tracker has already ended
at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.endWithError
```

Actually the code is much longer but I think these are the relevant parts. Is it a known thing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Which version / checkout of the template are you running against?

Comment: The build.gradle Corda version is set to 0.13.0,however, I'm pretty sure it's from the git's master, I've cloned it with the Clone HTTPS feature, if this is not what you intended, how can I check the proper version/checkout?

Comment: Is this your own test, or an existing test? I can't find this test in the template codebase. It looks like you may be using `SignTransactionFlow` without overriding `checkTransaction`?

Comment: This is an existing test from https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-flow.html that I renamed, the second-last.
Btw, you are right, I didnt override checkTransaction....I didn't thought it was necessary because in the tutorial it wasn't pointed out, sorry! Is it mandatory to override it?

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to add a section after "Writing the Acceptor's Flow" with some examples of checkTransaction implementation, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks Stefano, that may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing `SignTransactionFlow`, you must override `checkTransactions`.

Comment: I've done it, I have     override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {}



in my code but I'm not sure what I shuold put inside it, the tutorial says:


 SignTransactionFlow already checks the transaction’s signatures, and whether the transaction is contractually valid. The purpose of SignTransactionFlow.checkTransaction is to define any additional verification of the transaction that we wish to perform before we sign it. For example, we may want to:

    Check that the transaction contains an IOUState
    Check that the IOU’s value isn’t too high

Comment: Here's an example from the cordapp-tutorial: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-tutorial/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt.